# Cached rendering depending on a parameter

Tags: 8, caching

I'm trying to render a template given a request parameter but I get the same result once the cache is set.

Let's say I have this template :

```html
-- {{ step }} -- {{ xxx }} --
{% if not step %}not step{% endif %}
{% if step == 1 %}step 1{% endif %}
{% if step == 2 %}step 2{% endif %}
```

And this preprocessor

```php
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    $variables['step'] = null;
    $variables['xxx'] = rand ();

    if ($request->query->has('step')) {
        $variables['step'] = $request->query->get('step');
    }
}
```

When I work with the cache template disabled, I get the expected resut, e.g when requesting `page?step=1`, I get `step 1`, `page?step=2`, I get `step 2` and so on. However, when the cache is enabled, the first page load is correct and the subsequent loads take the same markup (if I first load `page?step=1`, I get `step 1` whatever parameter I use after that).

How can I tell Drupal to process my variable even if the cache is enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the cache context `url.query_args` in preprocess:

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.query_args';
```

Or more specific:

```
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.query_args:step';
```